# How to categorize and compare datetime columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. I have a dataframe with a datetime column and a visit id column. I want to compare the number of visits that occurred in two periods of time to each other. Currently I'm doing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"VisitID":['1', '2', '4', '5', '6'],
"VisitDate": ['1/1/2023', '2/1/2023', '3/1/2023', '4/1/2023', '5/1/2023']})

df['VisitDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['VisitDate'])
# 3 label date categories
df["Categorize Date Range"] = pd.cut(df['VisitDate'], 
       bins=[pd.Timestamp("1/1/2023"), pd.Timestamp("2/2/2023"), pd.Timestamp("3/31/2023"), pd.Timestamp("5/1/2023")], 
       labels=['Dates: 1/1/2023 - 2/1/2023', 0, "Dates: 4/1/2023 - 5/1/2023"],
        include_lowest=True,
       right=True)
# filter out date categories I don't care about
df = df[(df['Categorize Date Range'] != 0) & (df['Categorize Date Range'].notnull())].copy()
# get count of each category
df.groupby(['Categorize Date Range'])['VisitID'].nunique()
```

This gives me the right output but I wonder if I'm missing something as it doesn't seem to be a very pythonic way of doing things.

Input:

| VisitID | Date of Visit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2023 |
| 2 | 2/1/2023 |
| 4 | 3/1/2023 |
| 5 | 4/1/2023 |
| 6 | 5/1/2023 |

Output:

| index | VisitID |
| --- | --- |
| Dates: 1/1/2023 - 2/1/2023 | 2 |
| Dates: 4/1/2023 - 5/1/2023 | 2 |

Comment: Can you please add an example/your definition of the dataframe? You're jumping directly into editing with your `pd.cut` without us being able to see the dataframe before that.. Could you please add that?

Comment: Ok, so what is the connection between the time intervals in the dataframe (you have 1 line for each day) and your desired output? I struggle to see a "logic" pattern (you group 2 days together, but days 1-2 and days 4-5). If your selection of what you want to show is fully manual/ad-hoc, then of course you have to exactly specify those. If there is a rule (e.g., group all data to weekly pattern), see answer below

Answer (score 1):

You want to **re-sample** your dataset based on your time axis, down to the right time interval. Then, you can easily apply whatever function you need.

So for example resample to "daily" intervals, and then apply a `count`, to get the number of visits at each day. You kind of already do this with your `pd.cut` operation, but that is quite manual and hard-coded vs a call to the more dynamic `df.resample`.

```
df.resample(on='VisitDate', rule='d').count()
```

Visit the [pd.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) documentation for how to set the most adequate "rule"

Comment: Is there a way to do that when the time periods are dynamic? Sometimes I'm looking for fiscal year, sometimes I'm looking for calendar year, and other times I'm looking for grant year (non profit year/s for receiving a grant) ?

Comment: Of course! That's what the `rule` arg is for... Only in the example here, we use `d` for daily, but you can naturally use other intervals, or define your own intervals, and also add offsets (say you want a "weekly" analysis, starting every Wednesday, so offsetting by 3 days) - or a "fiscal" year (say, running from Jul-Aug). Check the docs (I added the link above)

Comment: The one condition though is that the to-be-sampled data needs to be truly a `datetime` column.. If it's something categorical/text-based (so you as a human know intuitively how to sample it, but python/pandas cannot interpret the data), then of course you will need to manually define your sampling rule (e.g., using `pd.cut`, or `pd.groupby`)